# How to import custom html with DraftJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to write an editor with draftJS. Unable to import HTML structure correctly.
I changed the standard structure to my own. eg
It was

```
<p> <strong> BOLD </strong> <br> </p>
```

Has become

```
<p class="article_paragraph"> <span className="custom_bold"> BOLD </span> <br> </p>
```

And after that, when importing html data, the draft does not understand this structure. I use stateToHTML - draft-js-export-html

For example, there is data

```
<p class="article_paragraph"> <span class="custom_bold"> BOLD TEXT </span> <a class="custom_link" href=""> <span class="custom_bold"> 123 </span> </ a> </p>
```

After importing, I only get

```
<p class="article_paragraph"> BOLD AND ITALIC </p>
```

Please tell me what is the problem?

For clarity, I created a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-babbage-8m3up?file=/src/editor.jsx:314-334)
The structure of html lies in the data

const data = `<p class="article_paragraph"><span class="custom_italic"><span class="custom_bold">BOLD AND ITALIC</span></span></p>`;

```
export default function CustomEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(stateFromHTML(data), decorator)
  );
  return (
    <div className="CustomEditor">
      <Tollbar editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
      />

      <textarea
        disabled
        style={{ width: 800, height: 300, marginTop: 20 }}
        value={stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent(), getOptions())}
      />
    </div>
```